# Generate list of exposed RESTful URI's

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

In the past when working with Spring REST in a JVM as the application would bootup, just before the container would completely boot, the Spring MVC module would output a list of all the RESTful API's that it was configured to expose? I've since been unable to reproduce this in later versions of spring? I realise that doing so is a security risk if anyone can get a hold of your logs but I need a list of the REST calls exposed by our system as quickly as possible. If anyone has any suggestions I'd greatly appreciate it.

Thanks,
Mark.

Comment: Probably you want a list for "REST services consumers" that don't have and don't want to have access to the source code. In this case, you can use http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.enunciate/maven-enunciate-plugin . You just add some annotations + comments and it will generate an HTML file (+additional resources) as a documentation page. This can be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11939542/how-do-you-document-a-rest-api

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if it is exactly what you are looking for - we came up with an IndexController that renders a response containing all the Controllers that are annotated with [ExposesResourceFor](http://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/current/api/org/springframework/hateoas/ExposesResourceFor.html) in HATEOAS style. So we get entry points to the collection resource for every controller.

You could do something similar with your controllers annotated with RestController or RequestMapping.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/", produces = { "application/hal+json", "application/json" })
public class IndexController {
    private final Set<Class<?>> entitiesWithController;
    private EntityLinks entityLinks;
    private RelProvider relProvider;

    @Autowired
    public IndexController(ListableBeanFactory beanFactory, EntityLinks entityLinks, RelProvider relProvider) {
        this.entityLinks = entityLinks;
        this.relProvider = relProvider;
        Map<String, Object> beansWithExposesResourceForAnnotation = beanFactory.getBeansWithAnnotation(ExposesResourceFor.class);
        entitiesWithController = beansWithExposesResourceForAnnotation.values().stream()
                .map(o -> o.getClass().getAnnotation(ExposesResourceFor.class).value()).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = GET)
    public ResponseEntity<ControllerLinksResource> getControllerLinks() {
        ControllerLinksResource controllerLinksResource = new ControllerLinksResource();

        entitiesWithController.forEach(entityClass -> controllerLinksResource //
                .add(entityLinks.linkToCollectionResource(entityClass) //
                        .withRel(relProvider.getCollectionResourceRelFor(entityClass))));

        return ResponseEntity.ok(controllerLinksResource);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a million for that Zaddo, that appears to give you back every Controller annotated class in the jvm? Alas I'm looking for a list of all the exposed URI's. I've definitely seen this printed immediately before spring completes wiring and the tomcat server starts in the catalina.log. I'm really wondering how it is I turn it back on.

Comment: Hey - if it helped you could still upvote my anwer ;-) - The code above searches for controllers annotated with ExposesResourceFor - but you could change it to `@RestController` or `@RequestMapping`.  Do you mean such log entries? - `Mapped "{[/system/metrics/{name:.*}],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.Object ...` - I see them when my spring boot application is starting - the output comes from `org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping`

Comment: Bingo that's exactly what I'm looking for Mathias!! Apologies now I didn't realise I hadn't upvoted your answer! how do I flag this reply as the answer?

Comment: Hi There, I am unable to compile the code snippet. Can you pls post what you and how used.

Comment: should indicate spring's versions, because in 2019 this code does not compile, even though I am sure it is a great solution.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need REST API documentation, You can use any of the below Rest API documentation frameworks.

[Swagger](https://github.com/rlogiacco/swagger-springmvc)

[apiDoc](https://github.com/apidoc/apidoc)

[JsonDoc](http://jsondoc.org/examples-spring.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot Lovababu alas that would still mean trawling through each controller and updating them manually. It's definitely something I'll incorporate in the future but for right now I need a way of finding the list without having to touch each controller. we've lots :D